# how to change cell value daily

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the cell value on Sheet 1 Col A from "Yes" to "No" everyday at 9am without having open the workbook manually. For instance, if the cell value at Sheet 1 Col A is "Yes" today, it needs to show "No" tomorrow at 9am. However, I can't make it changed automatically at that specific time. Can anyone help? Please see below for the example and my code. Thanks in advance.

***TODAY at 1pm***

```
 A  B
no  1
no  2
yes 3
no  4
yes 5
yes 6
yes 7
```

***TOMORROW at 9.01am***

```
 A  B
no  1
no  2
no  3
no  4
no  5
no  6
no  7

Option Explicit
Public rTime As Date
Sub time()
rTime = Now + TimeValue("00:09:00")
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=rTime, Procedure:="CellValueAutoIncr1", schedule:=True
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For k = 2 To lastrow
If Sheet1.Cells(k, 1).Value = "yes" Then
Sheet1.Cells(k, 1).Value = "no"
End If
Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to name your sub the same as a reserved word unless you are specifically trying to supercede the original functionality. `Time` returns the current time just as `Now` and `Date` return other system datetime values. By naming your procedure **Time** you've overwritten that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate sub procedure for setting the *no* values and have that sub schedule itself.

**Module1 code sheet**

```
Option Explicit

Sub timed_no()
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Date + TimeSerial(9, 0, 0) - CBool(TimeValue(Now) > TimeSerial(9, 0, 0)), _
                       Procedure:="make_No"
End Sub

Sub make_No()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) = "no"
    End With
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Date + 1 + TimeSerial(9, 0, 0), _
                       Procedure:="make_No"
End Sub
```

**ThisWorkbook code sheet**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    make_No
End Sub
```

You can force a manual **n** reset and schedule by calling **timed_no**. This may come in handy when you initially open the workbook. Manually schedule the next **no** reset by calling **timed_no**.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. Thank you for your response. I've tried your code and I've issue with that. I put make_No in ThisWorkbook. The code is still running even it's not at 9am. May I know how do I solve this issue?

Comment: I've provided labels for where the code is supposed to go. It is not intended to be different than that. I've tested it but I will run more severe tests to see what I come up with.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot reproduce your difficulties no matter what I try. I suspect that I do not have the full story. See [sample workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Timed_NO.xlsb).

Comment: wadr, that would have been nice to know beforehand. All of this new information seems to invalidate my original answer. I would  suggest you [close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this question and start another with the updated information lest this become a [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions).

Comment: Hi Jeeped. I'm sorry for the troubles and thanks a lot for your suggestion and help. I'll take note for next time when I ask question. I've changed by using other way in which I don't need this way for the time being. However, I won't close this question as your code might be very useful reference for anyone in the future.